# SSO to application with tomcat server on linux and windows with Active Directory

Tags: java, linux, windows, tomcat, single-sign-on

Im implemeting an SSO login feature for an application. Problem is that tomcat server need to be installed on linux or windows - so i cannt use waffle. 
I also dont want to use kerberos because i can't enforce client to generate keytab files and also application runs sometimes on localhost or intranet - SPN name is different for this case. Next problem is that i cant modify Active Directory structure (add new computer user etc.).
Finally i think that i should use NTLM to negotiate access to application. Is it right ?
Is there any library like waffle which can let tomcat to handle negotiate ? Or is there other way to do that ?

Comment: NTLM for SSO is called SPNEGO, which is based on kerberos.  Look here for a java implementation: http://spnego.sourceforge.net/.  You will still need to create entries for it in AD though (preauth user and SPN).

Comment: Forget it unless you intend to implement NTLM in the backend. Use Kerberos or leave it.